# Changing printer preferences when a printer is deployed through AD GPO

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I am deploying a printer through Group Policy. The deployment of the printer works great. The problem I'm having is, I made same changes to the printer preferences from the server. I changed things like the page size, roll paper width, changed the orientation to landscape, etc (this is a plotter, btw). I would expect that these changes would be pushed out to the workstations but they're not.

I have tried deploying it a couple ways through group policy. I used the deployed printers. I also send it out as a replace in group policy. Neither of them send out the preferences.

I used to send it out through a logon script and I believe it did push out the settings that way. I would rather use the newer Group Policy settings to deploy printers rather than a logon script that doesn't always work.

Here is a screenshot of the preferences I'm talking about:

[image: My computer on left, server on the right.]

Anyone know how I can push these changes out?

Comment: Are those server settings coming from the print server itself (10.10.0.25), or are those printer settings on the DC or server you are creating the GPO from?  I'm pretty sure the client will use whatever the default printing preferences are on the print server itself.

Comment: They are on the print server itself. From previous experience, they should use the defaults that are on the print server however with the newer Deployed Printers in group policy, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the answer:

Go to Printer Properties (not preferences). 
Click Advanced and then click Printing Defaults.

Make the changes there instead.